# Torah and Non-Believers, a/k/a, Scientists and Atheists

Tags: science, faith-bitachon-emunah

Is there evidence in the Torah of people who did not believe in Hashem or any other god(s)? I am specifically inquiring of those who believed in what today would be called science or atheism/secularism. It seems that the bible refers only to believers of faith whether monotheistic or polytheistic. In other words, when did total rejection of faith and acceptance of scientific or atheistic belief exclusive of G-d or gods develop? Since it is said that Adam believed in G-d, it appears faith was part of creation. By whom and when (if ever) was faith rejected according to scripture?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. You seem to already be aware that atheism/secularism didn't really exist (though materialism did, see Isaiah 22:13, for example) so are you asking for where the Bible may have predicted a phenomenon that didn't yet exist in its own time?

Comment: @matt I am not sure if the Torah did or did not address non-believers in G-d or gods. That is essentially what I am asking. If what you are saying is true, that atheism/secularism did not exist during biblical times, then your response answers my question. But are you sure that the Torah never mentioned or implied people who did not believe in G-d or gods? Concerning Isaiah, there seems to be other incidences of materialism in the bible but materialism does not preclude faith in G-d or gods. I am seeking evidence of total rejection of faith, and just what those people believed instead.

Comment: One more thing Matt. I am not sure why you state that you don't understand what I am asking. Your response clearly says that you do! But to clarify, Adam's belief in Hashem did not mean that pagans were not later identified in the Torah. So I still am asking, but rephrasing, was there any mention in Torah of atheists or people who explained spiritual phenomenon using early scientific methodology?

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentance of your question, but now I think I do

Comment: ...though I don't really understand what you mean by 'scientific methodology'. The most 'scientific' thing in the Bible is that God's power is proven by experiment (such as in Numbers 16:29-30 and Kings I 18:24)

Comment: wasnt it the greeks who adopted this as a nation?

Comment: @matt scientific methodology involves using observation of natural phenomenon to draw conclusions and develop methods (experiments) to recreate the same results. I am not 100% sure, but wasn't there, for example, some scientific attributes in designing Noah's ark, the Tower of Babel, the Holy Temples, the establishment of the calendar?

Comment: @ray. The Greeks were certainly great at philosophy, which certainly laid the ground work for scientific inquiry due to the philosophers established theory of logic and reasoning. Interestingly, a recent edition of Jewish Press's "Torah Riddles" column claimed that ultimately Aristotle concluded that Judaism was correct about most things.

Comment: Terms like 'science' gets vague when applied to things before science really existed. To me, science refers to knowledge that can/has been tested by controlled experimentation. This was conducted by Moses and Elijah (see above), but nothing like it would have really existed as an alternative to religion - it would have just been like any other myth, like idolatry

Comment: Though perhaps you are looking for something like in Job, chapter 21...?

Comment: Hi @matt. According to this article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_science. Science may have existed during biblical times after all. Your quotes from Psalms are very convincing as far as atheism is concerned. It certainly suggests non-belief in G-d or gods existed in David's time, but I am still wondering if it did even earlier. I'd like to wait a day or two to see if others respond before marking my question based on your response below as "answered." Again, for someone who claims he doesn't understand my question, you seem to understand it just fine. thank you for your responses.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand better (though soon we should clean up and delete all these comments). I don't disagree with you, I'll just repeat that "terms like 'science' get vague when applied to things before science really existed"(the article you linked notes that the term "scientist" wasn't used until William Whewell). It depends if early science is synonymous with what Medieval scholars called 'natural philosophy', but the early natural philosophers didn't have such a good way of showing that their own theories were better than alternative myths in a way that would challenge religion

Comment: @Matt You don't necessarily have to delete comments where they could help other people understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the whole, even the wicked people (or idolators) of the Bible do believe in some form of theism, even if not monotheism or the God of Israel, יקוה. To quote the [Encyclopedia of the Bible and Its Reception](http://www.degruyter.com/view/db/ebr) on "Atheism":

> The theoretical objection to the idea of the existence of god(s) is beyond the intellectual world of ANE [Ancient Near East] and HB/OT [Hebrew Bible/Old Testament]

Thus, the Bible doesn't speak about atheism or secularism as a widespread phenomenon or something worth warning about. Having said that, though, there do seem to be a few stray references to those 'fools' or 'wicked people' who deny the existence of *any* God, though some interpret this to specifically be a rejection of the God of Israel.

For example, there's [Psalm 14:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t2653.htm) and [Psalm 53:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2653.htm)

> אָמַר נָבָל בְּלִבּוֹ אֵין אֱלֹהִים - The fool hath said in his heart: 'There is no God' (JPS translation)

and similarly [Psalm 10:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2610.htm), regarding the wicked

> רָשָׁע- כְּגֹבַהּ אַפּוֹ בַּל-יִדְרֹשׁ; אֵין אֱלֹהִים כָּל-מְזִמּוֹתָיו - The wicked, in the pride of his countenance [saith]: 'He will not require'; all his thoughts are: 'There is no God.'

Comment: Thank you Matt. As I stated elsewhere, before marking your answer as "answered" I would like to give it some more time to see if there are any additional insights. As it is almost 2.30 AM in NYC, I don't think there are that many mi yodeyaites up now. I got to wake up at 5 to get to work so I am going to try to get a couple hours of sleep. Boker Tov.

Comment: @JJLL FWIW, the common term is "[Yodeyan](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1763/5151)".

Comment: @Scimonster FWIW, it was suppose to be funny.

Answer (score 1):

The Midrash Rabah on parsha Bereishis:

> And Cain said to Hevel: "…There is no Judge and judgment and no
>   World-to-Come and no reward for the righteous and no recompense for
>   the wicked…

http://www.aishdas.org/midrash/5765/Bareishis.htm

Comment: Midrashim like this appear in multiple places about multiple people (Nimrod, Eisav, etc.) but this isn't in the Bible

Comment: @ray. Does this suggest that Cain lacked faith in G-d?

Comment: @JJLL sounds good